# Stop Selenium WebDriver from showing the download manager when downloading .doc

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've got this code:

```
fxProfile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/msword; application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; application/octet-stream");
```

Right now it does **not** show the download manager (or whatever is the thing that asks you if you'd like to save or open the file) for the **.docx** format, but it keeps showing for **.doc**.

The MIME for .doc is "application/msword" and as you can see it is included in the profile. This is what makes the showing up of the download manager completely unexpected.

Comment: What does it do for an octetstream? Does it also open the download manager? Also, are you 100% sure that the mimetype of the file you are downloading IS that of .doc?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs, yes I have checked the MIME after manually downloading the file. The octet-stream means that I do not know what the file is, but I tried only with `application/msword` and I still get the download manager.

Comment: Might be a long shot, but could you check your local registry for HKCR\.doc\Content Type and see if that's set to application/msword? And do you have a way of checking the mimetype of the file on the server?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs, yes, the registry shows `application/msword`. I do not have way of checking the MIME type on the server, but I am not sure how that would help either.

Comment: My thought is that the file on the server somehow has a different mimetype than the extension indicates, confusing the browser.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs, I just tested - I used all possible MIME types from [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/) and the download manager STILL pops up.